# How can I add data to Dataextension for SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I am trying to add data to Data Extension using SSJS Script through Automation Studio.

1.I want to HTTP GET(ThirdParty's recomend)
2.I want to catch response(JSON) and add data to Dataextension

How can I do?

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var url = 'https://api.zipaddress.net/?zipcode=';
var response = HTTP.Get(url);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post your current SSJS code, and let us know exactly where you are stuck? Your question is very broad, as it covers both integrating with external API, parsing JSON and upserting to a DE

Comment: @LukasLunow
Thank you for comment.
First,
I want to integrating with external API.
However I can't check my response.
How do I check API status?

Comment: Hi @Janet222, the easiest way to check the response is to write it, eg. `Write(Stringify(response));`. You can also use try/catch for debugging.

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj
Thank you for comment.
If I write Write(Stringify(response)); 
How can I see  String data ?

Comment: Develop code on a CloudPage first, before moving it into Automation Studio. Write() will write to HTML, that is display results on screen

Comment: Thank you @zuzannamj 
I can get result on screen :)

Comment: No problem @Janet222 and please remember to accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example of an HTTP.Get call, parsing the response and writing it to a Data Extension. You can modify it for your needs and add exception handling.

Data Extension name: "Log"

JSON attribute logged: "explanation"

Script:

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
  try{

var apikey = ""; //pass apikey
var url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=";
var response = HTTP.Get(url +apikey);
var content = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.Content);
var log = DataExtension.Init("Log");
log.Rows.Add({explanation:content.explanation});

      }catch(e){
    Write(Stringify(e));
  }
</script>
```